# Integral of a cosine function

Tags: calculus, integration

I search the integral of this function : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! \frac{\cos(x^3)}{x^3} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Thank you.

Comment: This integral diverges.

Comment: Try a $u$-substitution, with $u=x^3$.

Comment: The Cauchy principal value exists (and can be found using symmetry).

Comment: @xpaul: A more rigorous $($and perhaps less confusing$)$ way of writing the integral is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\int_{-n}^{-1/n}f(x)~dx+\int_{1/n}^{n}f(x)~dx\bigg),$$ which clearly converges to $0$, due to symmetry with regard to the origin.

Comment: If we have a sine instead of the cosine, what can we find?

Comment: With $\large\sin$ you'll get something proportional to the Gamma function.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{\sin(x^k)}{x^n}dx\quad = \quad2^{^\tfrac{1-n}k}~\cdot~\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}k~\cdot~\dfrac{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12-\dfrac{n-1}{2k}\bigg)}{\Gamma\bigg(1+\dfrac{n-1}{2k}\bigg)}\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of your integrand, and what can we deduce from it ? :-)

Comment: my integrand is odd and I think that the result is zero :)